# TypeError: "list" argument must be an Array of Buffers - redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I receive

> buffer.js:359 throw new TypeError('"list" argument must be an Array of
>   Buffers'); ^
>
> TypeError: "list" argument must be an Array of Buffers at
>   Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:359:13) at ServerResponse.res.end
>   (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/app.js:58:33) at write
>   (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:175:9)
>   at send
>   (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:179:5)
>   at Immediate.
>   (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:113:5)
>   at Immediate.
>   (/home/mic3ael/src/prizmacloud/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15)
>   at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:585:18) at
>   tryOnImmediate (timers.js:543:15) at processImmediate [as
>   _immediateCallback] (timers.js:523:5)

when I try to redirect to external/internal url

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    return res.redirect('http://google.com');
}
```

I use express over nodejs.

```
node -v is 6.0.0
express -v is 4.13.4
npm -v 3.10.9
```

I tried without return and different urls inclusive externals and internals but it didn't work.

According [express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.location) is a correct way to redirect but it doesn't work.

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 2):

I found bug it was in app.js file at 58 line, The bug has been fixed by
`Buffer.isBuffer(chunk)` function.

Thanks.